# step file method for real numbers

Tags: java, gherkin

Feature: Addition of decimal Feature

```
Scenario: Add two positive decimal numbers
Given I am on the demo page
When I add the numbers 2.25 and 3.25
Then the result is 5.5
```

I think the when method should be something like

```
 @When("^I add the numbers (-?\\d+\\.?\\d*) and (-?\\d+\\.?\\d*)$")
public void i_add_the_numbers_and(double x, double y) throws Throwable {
   demoPage.addNumbers(x, y);
}

@Then("^the result is (-?\\d+\\.?\\d*)$")
public void the_result_is(double sum) throws Throwable {
    assertEquals(demoPage.getCalculatorResults(), sum);
}
}
```

The problem is that the number regex is not matching real numbers. example -1.2 or 5.4 or -23.234

How do I match all postive and negative real numbers?

Comment: Why do you want to match negative numbers, when on the second line of your question you state `Scenario: Add two positive decimal numbers`. Also, you shouldn't be using floating point datatypes for this kind of problem, because the rounding will cause you a headache. Use `BigDecimal` instead.

Comment: eventually I will add 5.43 and -6.454334. I will move to big decimal.

Answer (score 0):

thanks NeplatnyUdaj

the following works

```
/**
 * @param x
 * @param y
 * @throws Throwable
 */
@When("^I add the numbers (-?\\d+\\.?\\d*) and (-?\\d+\\.?\\d*)$")
public void i_add_the_numbers_and(float x, float y) throws Throwable {
  demoPage.addNumbers(x, y);
}

 /**
 * @param sum
 * @throws Throwable
 */
@Then("^the result is (-?\\d+\\.?\\d*)$")
public void the_result_is(float sum) throws Throwable {
    assertEquals(demoPage.getCalculatorResults(), sum);
}
```

so why would using float or BigDecimal cause the method to work?  My understanding is that double is a longer version of float.  so if float works why won't double

Comment: float won't work for all values. It appears to work for those particular values in your test, because the error due to loss of precision on the left-hand side equals the error due to loss of precision on the right-hand side.

Comment: I don't know Gherkin and these annotations or why your code doesn't work, but it might work for float and not double due to different precision. You should read about the Java datatypes to understand why it's not a correct datatype for you. You shouldn't assertEquals on a floating point value which comes from a calculation, because it's a hit or miss. Either use This assert, which allows specifying the delta: http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals(double,%20double,%20double) or go with BigDecimal.